# What is the order of a $2$-Sylow subgroup in $GL_3(F_5)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the order of  a $2 $-Sylow subgroup in$ GL_3(F_5)$ ?

My answer  : i  got  order of  a $2 $-Sylow subgroup is   $2^\frac{{3}{(3-1)}}{2} = 2^3$...

Is it correct  or not ?? pliz tell me

Comment: No, that is not correct. Presumably you used the formula for the order of the $p$-Sylow subgroup in $GL_n(F_p)$, but that only specifically works for the prime which is the order of the field, not for other primes.

Comment: can u   explain in detail  @ Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is 
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (p^n - p^i) = p^{\binom{n}{2}} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (p^{n-i} - 1).$$
The order of the 2-Sylow subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$ is the highest power of 2 dividing $|GL_3(\mathbb{F}_5)|$. This is equal to the highest power of 2 dividing $(5^3 - 1)(5^2-1)(5-1) = (124)(24)(4)$, which is $(4)(8)(4) = 2^7$.